# curl hanging on cygwin/windows XP

Tags: curl, cygwin, windows-xp

I'm trying a pretty basic `curl` command in cygwin on Windows XP.  It is supposed to download the `install.html` file into my local directory in a file called `output`.  It does something, but gives no indication of making any progress:

```
 curl -o output http://cygwin.com/install.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:38 --:--:--     0
```

I'm pretty sure my internet connection is plenty fast.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you perform other network functions from within Cygwin? Like pinging, for example?

Comment: @NewWorld, hmm, I guess not: `ping www.stackoverflow.com` gives me "Request timed out".  This seems like a productive line of thought -- but I have no idea for the next step ...

Comment: `ping` is a bad example; it requires certain privileges which you may not have.  `curl` definitely works (just double-checked on an XP VM), so it's a configuration issue on your end.  Can you `curl` other sites, and can you view that page in a browser?

Comment: @Yaakov, `curl www.stackoverflow.com` just hangs.  Of course, I'm having no trouble with `stackoverflow` from my browser.

Comment: Do you have an `/etc/resolv.conf` file in Cygwin?  Try removing it.